# Asigar Valor obtenido de una Base de Datos a un SELECT

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenas intento Asinar el Valor obtenido de una consulta a una **Base de Datos** a un ***select***

**Consulta en Base de Datos**

```
    <?php
       $lsq="SELECT DISTINCT opcion FROM tabla1";
       $quer = mysqli_query($con, $lsq);
         while ($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($quer)){
          $opcion=$raw['opcion'];
 <input type="hidden" id="opcion<?php echo $opcion; ?>"  value="<?php echo $opcion;?>" >
        }
    ?>
     <td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-info' href="#" onclick="enviar('<?php echo $numero_doc ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></td>
```

**este es un ancla que al presionarla obtendra el valor (opcion) me llamara la siguiente funcion**

```
 <a class='btn btn-info' href="#" onclick="enviar('<?php echo $opcion ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

**Funcio.JS**

```
function enviar(id)
{   
    var opcion= $("#opcion"+id).val();

    $("#selesct").val(opcion);
}
```

en dicha funcion recibo el valor ***(opcion)*** y lo asigno al **id** del select

**Select que debe recibir el valor y cambiar segun el valor recibido**

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <select class='form-control input-sm' id="selesct" name="selesct" readonly>
            <option value="">..Seleccione..</option>  
            <option value="1">CONTADO</option>
            <option value="2">CREDITO</option>                                
           </select>
        </div>
```

si el valor es 1 el select debe mostrar **CONTADO**, si es 2 **CREDITO**

Comment: Revisa este código porque probablemente no te salga ya qu no lo estas mostrando con un echo ni nada por el estilo.

while ($raw=mysqli_fetch_array($quer)){
          $opcion=$raw['opcion'];
 <input type="hidden" id="opcion<?php echo $opcion; ?>"  value="<?php echo $opcion;?>" >
        }
Delante del "<input" deberias haber puesto un echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer de está manera:

```
    function enviar(id) {
        var opcion = $("#opcion" + id).val();

        $('#selesct option[value="'+ opcion + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
```

Dependiendo de tu versión de jQuery se podría usar de otra manera:

```
$('#selesct option[value="'+ opcion + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: Que versions de jquery me recomiendas amigo @Raul y disculpa la tardanza!!yo utilizo esta
**<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> **  
**<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>**

Comment: Gracias por la Ayuda @Raul, he borrado cache del navegador y Listo!! utilizando tu codigo con el atributo **.prop** y el **<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> **